# How to create XML in Nokogiri with long namespace, divided by dots

Tags: ruby, xml, namespaces, nokogiri

I need to recreate this part of XML document in Nokogiri:

```
<propertiesJMeter>
    <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>
       true
    </jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>
</propertiesJMeter>
```

I build it with Nokogiri::XML::Builder like this, and here is only the questionable part:

```
propertiesJMeter {
  jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts 'true'
}
```

The result is incorrect, as I don't need that class variable and I want to save namespace structure:

```
<propertiesJMeter>
  <jmeter class="save saveservice thread_counts">
     true
  </jmeter>
</propertiesJMeter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer from "nokogiri-talk" group, which helped me

> The issue is that
>
> ```
> jmeter.save
> ```
>
> is interpreted by Nokogiri Builder as a "Tag Attribute Short Cut" (as
>   you can read about at
>   http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Builder).
>
> To make a tag with a "." in the tagname, you'll need to make sure ruby
>   doesn't interpret the "." as an instance method call. This works:
>
> ```
> propertiesJMeter {
>   send "jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts", 'true'
> }
> ```
>
> and emits
>
> ```
> <propertiesJMeter>
>   <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>
> </propertiesJMeter>
> ```